# Fitting a non-linear random effects model with binomial error structure

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, nonlinear-regression, random-effects-model

I've got a non-linear model that I've been applying to some data of repeated binary outcomes. I have data for multiple years, and I'd like to add random effects (by year) for two of my parameters. Looking at the `lme4` package in R, it seems that it supports non-Gaussian error structure and nonlinear models, but not simultaneously. Is there a way around this, or another package I could be using? I hear [ADMB](http://admb-project.org/) has a steep learning curve, so I'd prefer not to tackle that.

Without random effects, my model is quite simple--only 4 parameters and I've been able to fit it using a formula call to the `mle2` function from the `bbmle` package.

Comment: What's binary survival data? Do you mean repeated binary outcomes? (In which case `glmer()` would be appropriate, with `family=binomial`. "Survival data" outcomes are usually time-to-event, which wouldn't be binary.

Comment: @guest, yes, I do mean repeated binary outcomes. I was under the impression that `glmer` required a linear formula but perhaps I've misunderstood the differences between `glmer` and `nlmer`.

Comment: `glmer()` requires a linear formula but you get to pick the link function, and to use multiple terms in the linear formula, so there is considerable flexibility - but it won't fit everything. Other non-SAS alternatives are i) to write your own R code that integrates the random effects out of the likelihood, then maximizes ii) use WinBUGS/JAGS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is not possible in `lme4`, where you can pick any two of {nonlinear, mixed effects, binomial error error distribution}, but not all three. The better solution would be to use Stan/JAGS/BUGS.